# How to run built-in PHP 5.4 webserver from PHP file?

Tags: php, php-builtin-server

I am using built in php webserver and here is code i have written in my php file but not working.

```
exec("php -S localhost:8000 -t /home/test/");
```

Is there anything wrong?

Thanks

Comment: yeah path is absolute and right because if i execute same command from terminal,its working but not from php file

Comment: Do you get an error or some message?

Comment: Works for me, do `exec("php -S localhost:8000 -t /home/test/ 2>&1");` and see if you have errors

Comment: No error, but when i try to load localhost:8000 in browser,not loading content from folder.

Comment: @Stan: if i add  2>&1,it's working but stop the other process of that file and stick to display this command execution.

Comment: @Stan: i don't want to dispaly process performed by this command,is there anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
$lines = system("php -S localhost:8000 -t /home/test/", $output);
var_dump($output, $lines);
```

Then You should see what is wrong.